# Web Scrape page with multiple sections

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Pretty new to python... and I'm trying to my hands at my first project.

Been able to replicate few simple demo... but i think there are few extra complexities with what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to scrape the gamelogs for from the NHL website

Here is that i came up with... similar code work for the top section of the site (ex: get the age) but it fail on the section with display logic (dependent if the user click on Career, game Logs or splits)

Thanks in advance for your help

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.nhl.com/player/ryan-getzlaf-8470612?stats=gamelogs-r-nhl&season=20162017'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
Test = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': "gamelogsTable"})
```

Comment: After spending few hours, it looks like do not show up in the Python request... any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens with many web pages. It's because some of the content is downloaded by Javascript code that is part of the initial download. By doing does this designers are able to show visitors the most important parts of a page without waiting for the entire page to download.

When you want to scrape a page the first thing you should do is to examine the source code for it (often using Ctrl-u in a Windows environment) to see if the content you require is available. If not then you will need to use something beyond BeautifulSoup.

```
>>> getzlafURL = 'https://www.nhl.com/player/ryan-getzlaf-8470612?stats=gamelogs-r-nhl&season=20162017'
>>> import requests
>>> import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
>>> import lxml.html as html
>>> import lxml.html.clean as clean
>>> browser = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> browser.get(getzlafURL)
>>> content = browser.page_source
>>> cleaner = clean.Cleaner()
>>> content = cleaner.clean_html(content)
>>> doc = html.fromstring(content)
>>> type(doc)
<class 'lxml.html.HtmlElement'>
>>> open('c:/scratch/temp.htm', 'w').write(content)
775838
```

By searching within the file `temp.htm` for the heading 'Ryan Getzlaf Game Logs' I was able to find this section of HTML code. As you can see, it's about what you expected to find in the original downloaded HTML. However, this additional step is required to get at it.

```
              </div>
            </li>
    </ul>

    <h5 class="statistics__subheading">Ryan Getzlaf Game Logs</h5>

    <div id="gamelogsTable"><div class="responsive-datatable">
```

I should mention that there are alternative ways of accessing such code, one of them being `dryscrape`. I simply can't be bothered installing that one on this Windows machine.