# Python Xpath request returns empty list irregularly

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I know there are many similar questions, but I've been through all of those and they couldn't help me. I'm trying to get information from a website, and I've used the same method on other websites with success. Here however, it doesn't work. I would very much appreciate if somebody could give me a few tips!

I want to get the max temperature for tomorrow from [this website](http://www.weeronline.nl/Europa/Nederland/Amsterdam/4058223).

```
import re, requests, time
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('http://www.weeronline.nl/Europa/Nederland/Amsterdam/4058223')  
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
a = tree.xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/div[2]/div/li[1]/div/span/text()')
print(a)
```

This returns an empty list, however. The same method on a few other websites I checked worked fine. I've tried applying this method on other parts of this website and this domain, all to no avail.

Thanks for any and all help!
Best regards

Comment: This is because the xpath in this case is simply not valid. This alone returns nothing: `a = tree.xpath('//*[@id="app"]')`

Comment: I don't think that's the (main problem) though, when I check a different part of the website I get the same problem (xpath starting with /html/body/div etc). Thanks for the reply though!
It might be what @bill-bell suggested, the cookie problem.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you try to open that page you are asked whether you agree to allow cookies. (It's something like that, I have no Dutch.) You will  need to use something like **selenium** to click on a button to 'OK' that so that you have access to the page that you really want. Then you can use the technique discussed at [Web Scrape page with multiple sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433430/web-scrape-page-with-multiple-sections/43439808#43439808) to be able to get the HTML for that page, and finally apply whatever xpath it takes to retrieve the content that you want.

Comment: Indeed a request to allow cookies, I forgot I clicked through that. I'll try if I can figure something out with selenium, thanks!

Comment: Yes I saw that on the page too @Cobra , however even after visiting that page, there was no div with the id "app"

Comment: A quick last question. I am (as you may notice) not very experienced at Python. Would implementing selenium (or similar) into a script be a very tough project for a relatively new programmer? I'm doing this just to figure out scraping websites, and I could simply skip the ones containing cookie walls etc. I've been trying to get selenium to work for a few hours, but keep running into more and more things that I do not understand.
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Getting something to work can be a nightmarish experience. A big part of learning to program is simply dogged patience, not much more. What I still do when I'm learning something new in coding is to find a simple program that does something similar to what I want and then slowly adapt it, one step at a time until I achieve my goal. I google at every turn to understand points that are unclear.